# How to keep the shadow behind it fixed when a button is hovered?

Tags: html, css

When I use the hover effect on the button, the button and its background shadow move together. However, I want the shadow I use in the background to remain constant, only the button transform: translate(-5px, -5px); I want him to make his move. How do I provide this?

```css
.install span {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 1.0);
    color: #33302f;
    fill: #33302f;
}

.install {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(51, 48, 47, 1.0);
    width: 12rem;
    border: 1px solid #33302f;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease
}

.install:hover {
    transform: translate(-5px, -5px);
}

.install:hover::before {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
 <button class="install">
   <span>Install Theme</span>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `:hover`, you need to add 5px to your shadow offset, then make sure that your transition applies to `all` styles, not just `transform` styles.

```css
.install span {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 1.0);
    color: #33302f;
    fill: #33302f;
}

.install {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(51, 48, 47, 1.0);
    width: 12rem;
    border: 1px solid #33302f;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.install:hover {
    transform: translate(-5px, -5px);
    box-shadow: 11px 11px 0px rgba(51, 48, 47, 1.0);
}
```

```html
   <button class="install">
        <span>Install Theme</span>
    </button>
```